# How to break Flying Wyverns back part?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-portable

In monster hunter 3rd portable, how can I break the back part of **Flying Wyverns** like Rathian, Monoblos and so on?

I tried traps and attacking legs, but none of it really worked because by the time I get to their back they are either already up or I still can't reach their back.

Is there a way to break their back parts?

It seems it can only be done with ranged weapons.

If there is a youtube guide, I will be very appreciated.

Comment: I seem to remember the back part being breakable for flying wyverns only when mounting was introduced in MH4.

Comment: @Nelson Well the back parts can still be broken in previous series, but I doubt it has mounting. I checked Monster hunter 3rd portable wiki but can't find mounting. Nevertheless, it still can be broken.

Comment: I know some monsters you can break the back, like the Zinogre, Duramboros, Uragaan, but Flying Wyverns' backs were simply not accessible.  I guess you can go bowgun them and see if they break.

I just remember you not being able to break their back because you can't get there.

Comment: I dunno how to do it with melee weapons but I broke the backs of many a rathalos with a bow in 3U. Arc shot spam was pretty good at it.

Comment: @Nelson I see I have misunderstood it. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

**You can't break it's back like in MH4.**

The "Back" of a flying wyvern type monster isn't breakable in 3rd generation games and below, however you can break it's **wings**.

While the wings have a wider attack area, they are still located on the back side of the monster and can be difficult to reach without a ranged weapon so using a ranged weapon would definitely be the easiest solution but you can still try to use one of the melee methods listed below.

Since they aren't really in range for sustained melee damage, your best try is to force the monster to fall over. This can be achieved by KOing, Traps or Staggering a monster while mid-air.

For flying wyverns that actually spend a lot of time mid-air your preferred weapons should be the ones that can reach up high enough to get the monster out of the air. Gunlances and switch axes are probably amongst the strongest for this task, since they have powerful, high reaching attacks that can force a flying monster to the ground in relatively few hits. Any other weapon with less range works aswell but they won't be as safe since you have to be very precise and maybe wait for the monster to initiate a low-flight attack which could potentially hit you.

For flying wyverns that don't spend a lot of time in the air, your best bet is to KO them (Hammers and Hunting horns are great at this) or to trap them and then simply run to the wings to break them. Getting to the back of the monster in time can be tricky but it's not impossible so practice is key.

An additional method would be putting the monster to sleep. Using barrel bombs on a sleeping monster will deal massive amounts of damage to a specific bodypart.

**Some useful links (Rathalos as an example)**

- [Rathalos drop/damage table](https://www.gamefaqs.com/psp/991479-monster-hunter-portable-3rd/faqs/61490#section28)
- [MH3U Kiranico Rathalos](http://kiranico.com/en/mh3u) - (I know this is a different game but a lot of things stay the same)
- [3rd generation damage effectiveness](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Rathalos#Damage_Effectiveness)

Comment: A Flash Bomb is the best way to get flying monsters to land.

Comment: Ah, I see I  have misunderstood the topic at the first place. Thank you so much for the answer. I wanted to farm some rare materials and thought it could only be done by breaking back parts, but that was misunderstanding. Thanks

Comment: Conversely, if you look at the [MH4u data](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/monster/rathalos), it gives you a "Break Back" reward.